# How to use Cloudmine as API in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Calling APIs via Cloudmine is very different on how to consume a REST or SOAP. Now I am having trouble in the syntax, the documentation in cloudmine website is in objective C, when I translate it to Swift, it gives me error. Here's my sample code for the function log in:

```
    user!.loginWithCallback({(resultCode: CMUserAccountResult!, messages: [AnyObject!]) -> Void in

        switch resultCode {
        case CMUserAccountLoginSucceeded:
            // success! the user now has a session token
            var token = user.token
            break

        case CMUserAccountLoginFailedIncorrectCredentials: break
            // the users credentials were invalid

        case CMUserAccountOperationFailedUnknownAccount: break
            // this account doesn't exist

        }

    })
```

I just converted it from objective c code which is:

```
[user loginWithCallback:^(CMUserAccountResult resultCode, NSArray *messages) {
    switch(resultCode) {
    case CMUserAccountLoginSucceeded:
    {    // success! the user now has a session token
         NSString *token = user.token;
         break;
    }
    case CMUserAccountLoginFailedIncorrectCredentials:
        // the users credentials were invalid
        break;
    case CMUserAccountOperationFailedUnknownAccount:
        // this account doesn't exist
        break;
    }
}];
```

Now it gives me error:

> Cannot convert value of type *'(CMUserAccountResult!, [AnyObject!]) ->
>   Void'* to expected argument type *'CMUserOperationCallback!'*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite embarrassing, I just looked at what the init of message, and it turns out it must be [AnyObject]!

So I just changed the code to:

```
user!.loginWithCallback({(resultCode: CMUserAccountResult, messages: [AnyObject]!) -> Void in

    switch resultCode {
    case CMUserAccountLoginSucceeded:
        // success! the user now has a session token
        var token = user.token
        break

    case CMUserAccountLoginFailedIncorrectCredentials: break
        // the users credentials were invalid

    case CMUserAccountOperationFailedUnknownAccount: break
        // this account doesn't exist

    }

})
```